# Column-Count: auto CSS makes images disappear after 1 column

Tags: html, css, image, multiple-columns

I am currently just trying to create a responsive mock up with the following code and it looks fine as a single column in the mobile layout but as soon as it reaches a resolution large enough for 2 or 3 columns the images and button in the top right corner disappear unless they are still in the 1st column. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d6rs4abw/1/

This is the main area that I am fighting with but I could be wrong somewhere else that is effecting my overall css

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer, This is one of the first layouts Ive ever done so take it easy on me

```
  ul#products {
margin:1em 0;
padding-left:1em;
-webkit-column-count:auto;
-webkit-column-gap:2.5em;
-webkit-column-width: 310px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at animation properties, for instance `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` set for `.flip` and `face`: looks like this property causes invisibility.

Comment: Those properties are used to flip the image within the box and do not help in bringing the images back